# Kernel of an induced map on a tensor product from a bilinear map.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request, modules

Suppose that $A,B,C$ are $R$-modules for $R$ a commutative unital ring, and

$$
\mathcal{B} : A \times B \to C,
$$

is an $R$-bilinear form inducing a map on the tensor product

$$
\tilde{\mathcal{B}} : A \otimes_R B \to C,
$$

where

$$
\tilde{\mathcal{B}}\left( \sum_i \left(a_i \otimes_R b_i\right)\right) = \sum_i  \mathcal{B}(a_i,b_i).
$$

Then is there a general method to characterise $\ker\tilde{\mathcal{B}}$?

We can make the following simple statement: If

$$
\iota : A \times B \to A \otimes_R B,
$$

is the canonical homomorphism, then we know that $\mathcal{B} = \tilde{\mathcal{B}}\circ \iota$, so

$$
\ker \mathcal{B} = \ker{\iota} + \iota^{-1}\left( \ker\left( \tilde{\cal{B}}_{\big \vert \iota(A \times B)} \right) \right),
$$

and so in particular

$$
\ker\left( \tilde{\cal{B}}_{\big \vert \iota(A \times B)} \right) = \iota(\ker\mathcal{B}),
$$

but can we make any statements more general than this? Any comments or even just reference suggestions would be greatly appreciated.